# Perl 5.12.3 C/C++ code crashes in PUSHMARK(SP) ; with segmentation fault on Solaris 5.9

Tags: c++, c, perl

I have a C/C++ code which uses perlcall  to invoke perl scripts and was working with Perl version of 5.8.90. Due to some memory leaks/heap corruption in 5.8.90, we planned to use 5.12.3, the latest version of perl.

While using the libperl.so of 5.12.3 version, our program is crashing while calling "  PUSHMARK(SP) ;"
I tried to debug in dbx but could get only the below information
t@32 (l@32) terminated by signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address)

Please let me know if any body came across this problem. Any pointers to find the root cause would be very helpful.

Comment: can you provide a minimal snippet of C/perl code that demonstrates the problem?  also, in probably about a week, 5.14.0 will be the latest version of perl.

Comment: Ysth - Thanks for the information. Actually, while building my binary, I hadn't copied the new header files from 5.12.3 to correct path. After using the new header files, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Can you marked this as solved.

Comment: @yogishaj, You should accept the answer that you posted so that the question doesn't show up as unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm closing the thread based upon my research.

Ysth - Thanks for the information. Actually, while building my binary, I hadn't copied the new header files from 5.12.3 to correct path. After using the new header files, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible if your program is trying to access a memory location not in your program's address space.

The memory accessed either belongs to OS or some other process.

Check your code for this.